# GAS email sheet as PDF file sends corrupted attachment

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below was working fine, and then it suddenly started sending corrupted PDF attachments.

```js
function main(){
  setFormat();
  emailSpreadsheetAsPDF();
}

function setFormat() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email Sablon');
  var range1 = sheet.getRange('A5:O');
  range1.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
}

function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  const sheetToPrint = "Email Sablon"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the sheets to use
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email Sablon').getRange('B6').getValue().toString(); // grab the email address 
  const sml_number = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email Sablon').getRange('B11').getValue().toString(); // grab the sml number
  const s_o_number = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email Sablon').getRange('C11').getValue().toString(); // grab the s/o number
  const container_number = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email Sablon').getRange('B8').getValue().toString(); // grab the container number
  const subject = `Arrival Notice - ${sml_number} - ${s_o_number} - ${container_number}`; // the subject of the email
  const body = emailBody; // body of the email
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nC1v_GKo23BhbRMSDanu2tMeVEVDyty3EV4rgXDNRz8" + "/export?"; // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    +'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    +'&size=A4' // size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    +'&portrait=false' // orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    +'&fitw=true' // fit to page width (false for actual size)
    +'&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    +'&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    +'&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +'&gid='+shID; // the sheet's Id
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached PDF file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `Arrival Notice - ${sml_number} - ${s_o_number} - ${container_number}` + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}
```

I can not seem to figure out what the issue is (I haven't changed anything), so I would highly appreciate any help that I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this has done the trick:

Changing the `url` and `exportOptions` from

```js
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nC1v_GKo23BhbRMSDanu2tMeVEVDyty3EV4rgXDNRz8" + "/export?"; // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    +'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    +'&size=A4' // size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    +'&portrait=false' // orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    +'&fitw=true' // fit to page width (false for actual size)
    +'&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    +'&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    +'&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +'&gid='+shID; // the sheet's Id
```

to

```js
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()+'/'; // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    'export?format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    +'&size=A4' // size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    +'&portrait=false' // orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    +'&fitw=true' // fit to page width (false for actual size)
    +'&sheetnames=false' // hide name of sheet
    +'&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    +'&pagenumbers=false' // hide page numbers
    +'&gridlines=false' // hide gridlines
    +'&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +'&gid='+shID;
```

---

Also, the email call was changed from

```js
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `Arrival Notice - ${sml_number} - ${s_o_number} - ${container_number}` + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
```

to

```js
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [blob.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
    });
```

As a result of the latter change, I lost the ability to define a file name, but at least it works now.

---

The complete working code for anyone who may need it (or feels like improving it):

```js
function main(){
  var temp = setFormat();
  emailSpreadsheetAsPDF();
}

function setFormat() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email Sablon');
  var range1 = sheet.getRange('A5:O');
  range1.setNumberFormat('@STRING@');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  return true;
}

function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  const sheetToPrint = "Email Sablon"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the sheets to use
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email Sablon').getRange('B7').getValue().toString(); // grab the email address 
  const sml_number = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email Sablon').getRange('B13').getValue().toString(); // grab the sml number
  const s_o_number = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email Sablon').getRange('C13').getValue().toString(); // grab the s/o number
  const container_number = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Email Sablon').getRange('B9').getValue().toString(); // grab the container number
  const subject = `Arrival Notice - ${sml_number} - ${s_o_number} - ${container_number}`; // the subject of the email
  const body = emailBody; // body of the email
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()+'/'; // url of the spreadsheet
  Logger.log(url);

  const exportOptions =
    'export?format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    +'&size=A4' // size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    +'&portrait=false' // orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    +'&fitw=true' // fit to page width (false for actual size)
    +'&sheetnames=false' // hide name of sheet
    +'&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    +'&pagenumbers=false' // hide page numbers
    +'&gridlines=false' // hide gridlines
    +'&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +'&gid='+shID;
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},muteHttpExceptions:false};
  Logger.log(url+exportOptions);

  // generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  var blob = response.getBlob(); 

  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached PDF file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [blob.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
    });
}
```